# How can I import product image from an external URL in magento 1.9

Tags: import, image

```
$simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$simpleProduct->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose say we have a csv with an extra field: external_image_url for product import.

1> Copy app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php to the local code pool so that new path looks like:
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php

2> Open the Product.php from local code pool and search for the following code within saveRow() function:

```
foreach ($imageData as $file => $fields) {
    try {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . trim($file), $fields);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {}
}
```

Add the following code just below it:

```
/** EXTERNAL IMAGE IMPORT - START **/
$image_url  = $importData['external_image_url']; //get external image url from csv
$image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); //find the image extension
$filename   = md5($image_url . $importData['sku']).'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement
$filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; //path for temp storage folder: ./media/import/
file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder
$mediaAttribute = array (
        'thumbnail',
        'small_image',
        'image'
);
/**
 * Add image to media gallery
 *
 * @param string        $file              file path of image in file system
 * @param string|array  $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image',
 *                                         leave blank if image should be only in gallery
 * @param boolean       $move              if true, it will move source file
 * @param boolean       $exclude           mark image as disabled in product page view
 */
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, false, false);
/** EXTERNAL IMAGE IMPORT - END **/
```

more info [here](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/)