# import product image from external url

Tags: magento-1.9, product, import, image

I want to add product images from external url.. I have created CSV file for image uploading..When I click run profile popup button it displays "image not exist" error..`http://intow.co/admin/backEnd/uploads/4717602016_05_12_03_28_35pm.png`(image url)

Answer (score 3):

Using Magento's default Import or Dataflow Import doesn't allow you to download and assign an image via a CSV import. You'll either have to download the image and upload it to the server with the correct path in your CSV or you can look at a 3rd party tool like Magmi for importation.

Magmi's documentation is fairly solid and will allow you to download and assign a product an image via a CSV import.

Magmi's Documentation can be found here - http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

I would also ensure that the link you're providing the `image` field is valid and displays the image when you access it in a browser, the one you have provided displays a page error/404.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose say we have a `csv` with an extra field: `external_image_url` for product import.

1> Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php` to the local code pool so that new path looks like: `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php`

2> Open the `Product.php` from local code pool and search for the following code within `saveRow()` function:

```
foreach ($imageData as $file => $fields) {
    try {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . trim($file), $fields);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {}
}
```

Add the following code just below it:

```
/** EXTERNAL IMAGE IMPORT - START **/
$image_url  = $importData['external_image_url']; //get external image url from csv
$image_type = substr(strrchr($image_url,"."),1); //find the image extension
$filename   = md5($image_url . $importData['sku']).'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement
$filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; //path for temp storage folder: ./media/import/
file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($image_url))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder
$mediaAttribute = array (
        'thumbnail',
        'small_image',
        'image'
);
/**
 * Add image to media gallery
 *
 * @param string        $file              file path of image in file system
 * @param string|array  $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image',
 *                                         leave blank if image should be only in gallery
 * @param boolean       $move              if true, it will move source file
 * @param boolean       $exclude           mark image as disabled in product page view
 */
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, false, false);
/** EXTERNAL IMAGE IMPORT - END **/
```

more info [here](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-import-product-images-from-external-url-in-magento/)

reference : [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107588/how-can-i-import-product-image-from-an-external-url-in-magento-1-9)