# How to set product images from external url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, product-images, external

I have created products in magento site. Now I want to load product images from external url.. how I will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a module, because Magento not support external images "out the box". As advice, you need to download images localy and after import.

As fast and simple one time solution use wget and load from file. For example:

1. Save all your urls to file (for example urls.txt)
2. Create folder **media/import** and copy urls.txt to this folder
3. Go to this folder and run the command

```
wget -i urls.txt
```

Wget download all your files to the folder and you can import them from local source.

If you need to run this process periodically, you definitely need to build a module or find free solution

If you want to show images directly from remote url, do the following:

1. Create custom attribute (for example custom_image) with input type text and put external link to this attribute.
2. Update your theme template (find template, where your images displayed and change `<img src="<?php echo $_product->getSmallImage() ?>" />` to `<img src="<?php echo $_product->getCustomImage() ?>" />`

Comment: when I run the command `wget -i urls.txt` getting an error like `-bash: wget: command not found`

Comment: You need to install wget. Run cat /etc/*-release and tell me you OS

Comment: ok.. i am using mac os x 10.7

Comment: Is there any way to load images directly from external url, instead of importing images in to the server

Comment: check [this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-and-configure-wget-on-os-x/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572153/os-x-equivalent-of-linuxs-wget) links to know, how to install wget on Mac OS. Or you can try [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107588/how-can-i-import-product-image-from-an-external-url-in-magento-1-9) solution

Comment: In product detail page, the images should be loaded from external url. It should not be downloaded. i.e directly shown from external url's.

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: ok.. Thank you..

Comment: yes.. its working..

Comment: ok.. I more doubt how can I add multiple image to a product using external urls?

Comment: I am having hundreds of products so in this case i need to import image url right...

Comment: You can add more  custom attributes and override template to use them. Or you can save your links as JSON object in one field and parse this string in your template.

Comment: ok.. how to save this url as JSON  object

Comment: Sorry for asking all these things .. I am new to this...